# Why does the find command also return the directories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I created a empty directories, and executed the following in the terminal

```
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ mkdir -p a/b/c
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ mkdir -p a/a/b
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ mkdir -p b/a
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ echo "c" > a/c
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ echo "c" > c
```

Tree shows the following
 mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ tree

```
.
├── a
│   ├── a
│   │   └── b
│   ├── b
│   │   └── c
│   └── c
├── b
│   └── a
└── c

7 directories, 2 files
```

Why does the following find command output this

```
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ find .
.
./a
./a/a
./a/a/b
./a/c
./a/b
./a/b/c
./c
./b
./b/a
```

Isn't `find` only suppose the look for FILES inside the specified directories, as per the `man find`:

```
find - search for files in a directory hierarchy
```

Why are all the sub-directories listed with the files ?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything in unix type operating systems is a file.  Your keyboard is a file, your hard drive is a file, find itself is a file.

Comment: [People saying "files" when they mean *only* "regular files" are not really POSIX-compliant](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). :)

Answer (score 5):

Directories **are** files.  Find can look for regular-type files using the `-type` option:

```
find . -type f ...
```

Or for directory type files:

```
find . -type d ...
```

---

> **-type** t
>
> > True if the file is of the specified type.  Possible file types are as follows:
> >
> > > ```
> > > b       block special
> > > c       character special
> > > d       directory
> > > f       regular file
> > > l       symbolic link
> > > p       FIFO
> > > s       socket
> > > ```